# Wrapper ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, wrapper

I have a wrapper that allows me in fonction the role of the user to go on a different component.
I would like to add one more role in the latter but I do not see how (the role is this one "parent")
If you have ideas I'm interested

Here is my wrapper :

```
export default class Wrapper extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  role: null
}
}

componentDidMount() {
let config = {
  headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${authentication.getToken()}`
  }
}
axios.get(`http://rec.mylittlegeek.school/api/whoami`, 
 config).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
this.setState({ role: response.data.role });
  }).catch(error => {
console.log(error);
})
}

render() {
return !this.state.role ?
"Loading ..."
: this.state.role === "admin" ?
<GeekSessions {...this.props} />
:
<GeekDashSessions {...this.props} />
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the prettiest, but I it should work. A new GeekParentSessions component for the parent role.

```js
return ({!this.state.role ?
  "Loading ..."
  : this.state.role === "admin" ?
  <GeekSessions {...this.props} />
  :
  this.state.role === "parent" ?
  <GeekParentSessions {...this.props} />
  :
  <GeekDashSessions {...this.props} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise nesting more conditionals in your ternary, just use a classic if to make it more readable:

```
render() {
  const { role } = this.state;

  if (!role) {
    return <div>Loading ...</div>;
  }

  if (role === 'parent') {
    return <GeekParentSessions {...this.props} />;
  }

  if (role === 'child') {
    return <GeekChildSessions {...this.props} />;
  }

  return <GeekDashSessions {...this.props} />;
}
```